# Regex for All Digits but Not Exclusively Zeros

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex that matches inputs that:

- are non-empty AND
- are not exclusively zeros (although leading zeros are fine) AND
- have no non-digits

Put another way, the string must consist entirely of digits, but not exclusively zeros.

Comment: What patterns have you tried?

Comment: i guess `^0*[1-9]+\d*$`

Comment: @Pravneet_Singh - Yours does not work for 0001200.

Comment: @TomBaxter: That should work. @Pravneet_Singh edited it later to `^0*[1-9]+\d*$`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a couple lookaheads:

```
 ^(?!0*$)(?=\d+$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/fTgsWE/3/

Answer (score 0):

Or speed version (avoid look around altogether  )

`^\d*[1-9]\d*$`